# Many components in one file using Vue 3 Composition style

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I'm quite new in Vue

I try to make component that would have list with endeless possibility of nesting
So i think if its possible to make in same another component(cause it will be used only in this component) that would do jobe of nesting like recursion

(Concept not real code)

```
            <template>
                //Some stuff

                <NestingComponent :elements="list"></NestingComponent>

                //Some stuff
            </template>

            <NestingComponent :elements="element.childrens">
                <ul>
                    <li v-for="element in elements">
                        <NestingComponent v-if="element.childrens" :elements="element.childrens">
                        </NestingComponent>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </NestingComponent>
```

Or maybe is there a better way?

Comment: Generally that's the way.

Comment: what is the problem with that way?